# Creating an automated google meet link through google calendar and google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

What is wrong here as I don't understand what's the error? I am new to appscript in sheet so I don't know much..
I'm just trying to create google meet link as well as the calendar altogether for the future events prior to it happening.
I have corrected the miscopied codes. Now this is the error

**Error
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'res' before initialization
create_Meet @ Code.gs:45**

```
function create_Meet(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Google_Meet_Events");
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:E" + last_row).getValues();
  

  for(var i = 0;i< data.length;i++){
    var event_name = data[i][0]
    var start_time = data[i][1]
    var end_time = data[i][2]
    var des = data[i][3]
    var attendees = data[i][4]

    const gmt = "+05:30"
    const cal_id = "utgfkuy.google.com"

    const resource = {
      start: {dateTime : start_time+gmt},
      end: {dateTime : end_time+gmt},
      attendees: [{email: attendees}],
      conferenceData: {
        cerateRequest:{
          requestID: "sample123",
          conferenceSolutionKey:{type: "hangoutsMeet"},
        },
      },
      summary : event_name,
      description: des,

    };
    const res = Calendar.Events.insert(res, cal_id,{
      conferenceDataVersion: 1
    });

  Logger.log("Events have been added to the calendar");
  }  
}
```

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot know the error line in your script, in your script, `end: {dateTime = end_time+get},` and `summary = event_name,` should be `end: {dateTime : end_time+get},` and `summary: event_name,`, respectively. And, `resourse` is not used. From this situation, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this?

Comment: My guess is this line: `summary = event_name,` just telling us which line would be a lot easier if you actually want an answer.

Comment: `const res = Calendar.Events.insert(res, cal_id,` is the problem. It should read `const res = Calendar.Events.insert(resource, calendarId, {` Source: tanaikech [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/94791d48823e9659aa376cf7f0161d9b#google-apps-script)